# Android in Usb host mode list files in pendrive

Tags: android, file, usb, host, usb-drive

I have sony tablet S and I am connecting a pendrive to it.

I have found code that lets me:

- -Find the connected device
- -Find its interfaces
- -Find its endpoints (read, write)
- -I am able to open the device too

My question is:
How do I list all files and directories in the pendrive?

From what I have read there are methods like

```
mDeviceConnection.controlTransfer(...)
```

that allow to read and write to the pendrive but how do I list the files and directories in the pendrive?

I want to be able to get absolute paths to files contained in the pendrive so I can transfer them to the sd card on the tablet.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Issac I am looking for same functionality.Can you tell me how did you connect to device.I am trying from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html.

Comment: Has anyone got any solution to this question?

Comment: Hi Issac, please let me know if you got any solutions to your problem.

Comment: How do you create a file in pendrive from android code?

Answer (score 0):

Usually mounted pendrive are located in the folder `/mnt/` so, you can retrieve all files and folder from that folder.

```
File storageDir = new File("/mnt/");
if(storageDir.isDirectory()){
    String[] dirList = storageDir.list();
    //TODO some type of selecton method?
}
```

It may happen that the folder is different for some devices, ex. `/mnt/usb_storage/`

Comment: When I connect the pendrive to the tablet I can now the path to the pendrive. I have a tosat that says `dev/usb/002/002/`. When I put this path on the code you gave it does not list me the files in that path. Do I have to be in root mode to get acces to the files via my app? Do I need some kind of configuration?